# How to disable "always on" USB power on Macbook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, display, usb, sleep-wake, power

I am operating my MacBook Pro early 2015 within a Henge dock (HD03VA13MBPR) , connected to two external displays and external speakers. Both displays and speakers get power from a power distributer that offers a switch via USB. Whenever the USB has power, the monitors stay on. Take off USB power, and the displays shut down.

Now, that setup worked perfectly on my other computer, where USB Power could be configured. On my new powerbook the displays stay on. The USB Port seems to be "always on" during sleep mode.

How can I disable the "always on" function of the USB port while the MacBook is in sleep mode?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable individual USB ports by script?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/59764/how-to-disable-individual-usb-ports-by-script)

Comment: Not a Duplicate. I don't need the functionality "always on" entirely. The power of the USB port should be off while in sleep mode.

Comment: Can you share the model of Henge dock you are using?

Comment: sure: HD03VA13MBPR. Bought 4 Weeks ago.

Comment: I looked briefly at at https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT204377.  It may be the case that if "your Apple computer or display is asleep, all ports will provide their normal maximum output", which could be bad news.  However, the Henge dock appears to be designed for MacBooks, so we may need to keep digging.

Comment: I was hoping that this has improved with El Capitan but this is unfortunately not the case. Right?

Answer (score 1):

This seems not to be possible. I solved the situation now with the help of my dell external displyay. The USB-Hub there can be configured to shut down as soon as the display ist switched off. So the second display and the active speakers are connected to the power plug that can be switched off/on by USB power. This will allow with the klick of one button to switch all other devices off/on.